# Content-Disposition header is not being set on a file download

Tags: java, playframework-2.0

The following code works beautifully apart from the fact that the content-disposition header is never set and the file gets downloaded with an incorrect name.

I have scoured the Java APIs but cannot see a way to set the header. I have tried to set it in the apply function but the response object is null at that point. I have tried setting the header in the index function but it is ignored. Can someone explain where I am going wrong please? Many thanks.

```
package controllers;

import java.io.File;
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

import play.libs.Akka;
import play.libs.F;
import play.libs.F.Function;
import play.mvc.Controller;
import play.mvc.Result;

public class Application extends Controller
{
    public static Result index()
    {
        F.Promise<File> promiseOfFile = Akka.future(new Callable<File>()
        {
            public File call()
            {
                return new File("temporaryfilename.txt");
            }
        });

        response().setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=\"actualfilename.txt\"");

        return async(promiseOfFile.map(new Function<File, Result>()
        {
            @Override
            public Result apply(File file)
            {
                return ok(file);
            }
        }));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug that was fixed in Play 2.1.

See this blog post: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/play-framework/-RlqeZDHcFU